# Assigning values in DataFrame when columns names and values are in single row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two dataframes like below,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({1: np.zeros(5), 2: np.zeros(5)}, index=['a','b','c','d','e'])
```

[image]

and

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'category': [1,1,2,2], 'value':[85,46, 39, 22]}, index=[0, 1, 3, 4])
```

[image]

The `value` from second dataframe is required to be assigned in first dataframe such that the index and column relationship is maintained. The second dataframe index is `iloc` based and has column `category` which is actually containing column names of first dataframe. The `value` is value to be assigned.

Following is the my solution with expected output,

```
for _category in df2['category'].unique():
    df1.loc[df1.iloc[df2[df2['category'] == _category].index.tolist()].index, _category]  = df2[df2['category'] == _category]['value'].values
```

[image]

Is there a pythonic way of doing so without the for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
df3 = df1.reset_index()
df3.update(df2.pivot(columns='category', values='value'))
df3 = df3.set_index('index').rename_axis(None)
```

Alternative, reindex df2 (in two steps, numerical and by label), and [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) with df1:

```
df3 = (df2
 .pivot(columns='category', values='value')
 .reindex(range(max(df2.index)+1))
 .set_axis(df1.index)
 .combine_first(df1)
)
```

output:

```
      1     2
a  85.0   0.0
b  46.0   0.0
c   0.0   0.0
d   0.0  39.0
e   0.0  22.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way by replacing the 0s in `df1` with NaN; `pivot`ting `df2` and filling in the NaNs in `df1` with `df2`:

```py
out = (df1.replace(0, pd.NA).reset_index()
       .fillna(df2.pivot(columns='category', values='value'))
       .set_index('index').rename_axis(None).fillna(0))
```

Output:

```py
      1     2
a  85.0   0.0
b  46.0   0.0
c   0.0   0.0
d   0.0  39.0
e   0.0  22.0
```